# Is there a predetermined order that Database.SaveResult is returned?

Tags: apex, dml, order

Let's pretend the scenario below:

```
List<Account> acc = new List<Account>{...};

List<Database.SaveResult> results = Database.insert(acc, false);
```

Will the Lists have associated records in the same order?

```
List<Email> emails = new List<Email>();
for (integer i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
{
  if (!results[i].isSuccess())
  {
    //This is what I'd like to know if it would work.
    emails.add(new Email('acc name: ' + acc[i].Name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Per [the documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm) (emphasis added):

> An array of SaveResult objects is returned with the insert and update
>   database methods. Each element in the SaveResult array corresponds to
>   the sObject array passed as the sObject[] parameter in the Database
>   method, that is, **the first element in the SaveResult array matches the
>   first element passed in the sObject array, the second element
>   corresponds with the second element, and so on.** If only one sObject is
>   passed in, the SaveResult array contains a single element.