# jsforce library inserting array of elements

Tags: apex, jsforce

I am using the [`jsforce`](https://jsforce.github.io/document/) library and I have a question about if I insert an array of elements in an entity, it returns an array of elements sorted as they were inserted.

I have found that in APEX it does (source: [Is there a predetermined order that Database.SaveResult is returned?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45773/is-there-a-predetermined-order-that-database-saveresult-is-returned)) but I want to know if the `jsforce` library does the same.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, yes, they are returned in the same order as they are passed in. They basically call the underlying API, which returns values in the same order as they were received. I took a peek at the source, and it doesn't seem to be doing anything that would alter the order of the input/output parameters.